# Python code skips identifying the numbers

Tags: python

The python program that takes the numbers from the parent list and  creates a child list of numbers only. However, the output is not complete number list.
Nothing tried. New to python.

```
input = ['True','False',[1,2,3,4],2,1.2,4,0.44]
# str(i): changing int or float to str
    return [str(i) for i in l if (type(i) == int or type(i) == float) ]
    # append the  numbers if it is an int or a float
print(f"num_str = {num_str(input)}")

# Output:
# num_str = ['2', '1.2', '4', '0.44']
# 1 and 3 are missing in the list.
```

Comment: if you're asking about why the numbers in `input[2]` are not included, it's because type(input[2]) will evaluate to list, not int or float.

Comment: Why 1 and 3 numbers are skipped? The output is num_str = ['2', '1.2', '4', '0.44']

Comment: What do you mean by 1 and 3? What's your expected output?

Comment: Notice that `type([1,2,3,4]) == list`

Comment: Not just 1 and 3 missing but the whole list is not included. The 2 and 4 are coming from the values after the list as these are of type int.

Answer (score 0):

For simplification purposes i will take a 'simpler' input list as

```
input = ['True','False',1,2,3,4,2,1.2,4,0.44]

# Changed the '[1,2,3,4]' for '1,2,3,4'
# Than you can:
result_list = []
for item in input:
    if isinstance(item, (int,float)):
        result_list.append(item)
#
print(result_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1.2, 4, 0.44]
```

for it to work on the input you provided it would be better to 
look at the origin of the input and ponder if you could have lists inside lists inside lists as something like

```
a = [ 1,2,3,[10,"a",40,[56,"b"]],5,"string"]
```

if you can than it would be interesting to recursive check if the current item is a Iterable type, otherwise just add another for to deal with

```
b = [1,2,3,[5,6,"string"],7]
```